# E_NOTICE: Report only undefined variables

Tags: php, error-reporting, e-notices

I would like to see a single error when I am using an undefined variable, but it would be nice to avoid to see other E_NOTICE errors, is it possible ?

Comment: Probably with a [custom error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) that filters out messages you don't want. But are the other notices not something you'd like to fix or are able to fix?

Comment: You shouldn't hide other notice's.

Comment: In fact when I enable E_NOTICE errors my script takes years to run, I waited for 2 min and I stopped it (it usually lasts 10 seconds...). I guess it's because there are too much E_NOTICE errors, and php never ends because it load thousands of errors. My script is huge.

Comment: @sylvain1264 If that's the case, then something else must be going on with your code that should be fixed. I would suggest writing a new question after you have _narrowed down_ the part of your script which is generating the notices for assistance correcting it.  [There is advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index) on how to correct those particular errors.

Comment: If you write a new question to actually address the errors, be sure to limit it _only_ to a small part of the code which issues errors, and only a _small_ set of sample error messages, which show the line numbers related to the code posted.

Comment: Ok I found why I had so much E_NOTICES, if I run my whole script I have millions notices messages because my arrays are using keys like A instead 'A' so php tell me I use undefined constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially I would recommend against doing this, as it is quite possible to write PHP code that generates no warnings or notices. Indeed that should be your goal - to eliminate all notices and warnings.

However, what you're asking would be possible to achieve using PHP's custom error handling via [`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), which accepts a callback function to run when an error is issued.

You would define the function to do string matching for `undefined index` and `undefined variable` in the error string `$errstr` callback parameter. You are then in effect overriding PHP's normal error reporting system, and substituting your own.   I would reiterate that I don't think this is a great solution.

```
$error_handler = function($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
  if (in_array($errno, array(E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE))) {
    // Match substrings "undefined index" or "undefined variable"
    // case-insensitively. This is *not* internationalized.
    if (stripos($errstr, 'undefined index') !== false || stripos($errstr, 'undefined variable') !== false) {
       // Your targeted error - print it how you prefer
       echo "In file $errfile, Line $errline: $errstr";
    }
  }
};

// Set the callback as your error handler
// Apply it only to E_NOTICE using the second parameter $error_types
// so that PHP handles other errors in its normal way.
set_error_handler($error_handler, E_NOTICE);
```

Note: The above is not automatically portable for languages other English. But if it is only for your own purposes or limited use, that's maybe not a problem.

Comment: Using php 5.2.17 this code doesn't compile. I think I can't use function in this way. I have this error at first line: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'."

Comment: Nevermind, you wrote this very fast with some mistakes ^^, i can fix this alone. Thanks for your useful help.